# Can a generic parameter stay generic in its definition (c#)

Tags: c#, templates, generics

I know I can do this

```
public void SetSomeValue<TGeneric, T> (
    ClassA<TGeneric> myObjectA, Tvalue)
    where TGeneric: IGenericType<T>           // IGenericType is an interface
    {
        ...
    }
```

but how is it possible to do something like this? The code below gives me the error `UnexpectedToken Cannot resolve symbol 'T'`

```
public void SetSomeValue<TGeneric, T> (
    ClassA<TGeneric> myObjectA, Tvalue)
    where TGeneric: class<T>           // I don't know which class it is, I just want my class to take a generic type
    {
        ...
    }
```

I basically want to have TGeneric not to only be IGenericType, but anything that has < T>. It could be an interface, a class, or anything, as long as it contains< T>

Comment: You should read up about generic type constraints. There is no such constraint as `class<T>`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I've read and expermented with it, that's how I managed to make it work for an interface class that contain the template, but wanted to extend this to much more. Is the only alternative to have thousand of function, one for each existing class/interface that contains that template?

Comment: What do you want the meaning of `class<T>` to be?

Comment: It could be IGenericType<T> like my first example, but could be anything else, like any custom class that contains a generic type. It could be ClassA<T>, ClassB<T>, ClassC<T>, etc etc etc

Comment: Did you try `ClassA<TGeneric<T>>`? Not sure if that would work, though.

Comment: So can you explain what you want to achieve with such restriction? "generic class with one parameter" don't seem to be very useful restriction (as it does not restrict types too much). Based on "SetSomeValue" it feels like you expect "class<T>" to represent "a class that has a property of type T" but obviously generic type does not even have to have a property...

Comment: *"It could be an interface, a class, or anything, as long as it contains< T>"*. Firstly, the `class` constraint literally means that the generic type parameter has to be a class, so it couldn't be anything at all by definition. Secondly, what does *"contains <T>"* even mean? Many types have a single generic type parameter but it gets used differently within each type. The point of generic type constraints is to allow you to use instance of that type in specific ways. The `class` constraint means you can treat it as a class. What exactly are you trying to achieve in that regard?